# Update/modify QListWidgetItem

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

I would like to use `QWidgetList` to create a list where I can add and delete items automatically, without the user having to interact with the graphical interface. I have this done, but I can't update/modify the text I put in the item when I created it. I have created four items like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  QListWidgetItem *lwi = new QListWidgetItem();
  lwi->setSizeHint(QSize(200, 20));
  lwi->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
  lwi->setText(QString("Obstacle ") + QString::number(i));
  ui_.list->addItem(lwi);
}
```

And I have seen that I can modify the text like this:

```
ui_.list->item(0)->setText(QString::number(updateItem, 'f', 2));
```

Where `updateitem` is constantly changing its value.

The problem is that it seems that although the text is modified, but it is updated on screen only when I interact with the window.

Is there any way to update it directly without having to interact? For example, if I do the same with a Label it works correctly and the Label changes its text constantly without the need to interact with it.

I am working with the rqt library for ROS, to develop a plugin created with Qt. Although I believe my problem is directly related to Qt and not to ROS.

Thank you.

EDIT1: I added `ui_.list_movil->update()` but is not working for me.

```
void MyPlugin::update_list()
{
  if (flagFirstItem == false)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      QListWidgetItem *lwi = new QListWidgetItem();
      lwi->setSizeHint(QSize(200, 20));
      lwi->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
      lwi->setText(QString("Obstacle ") + QString::number(i));
      ui_.list_movil->addItem(lwi);
    }
    flagFirstItem = true;
  }
  if (flagFirstItem == true)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < ui_.list_movil->count(); ++i)
    {
      ui_.list_movil->item(i)->setText(QString::number(updateItem, 'f', 2));
      ui_.list_movil->update();
    }
  }
}
```

I am adding four items just one time and after that I am trying to modify them. It is not working fine for me because I must click on an item to see the changed text. If I am doing it right, maybe it should be an error with [rqt library](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Tutorials/Create%20your%20new%20rqt%20plugin).

By the way, I am modifying labels like that:

```
void MyPlugin::imuEuler_callback(const sensor_msgs::Imu msg)
{
  if ((ros::Time::now().toSec() - updateTimeImuEuler) >= updateTime)
  {
    ui_.label_rollValue->setText(QString::number(msg.orientation.x, 'f', 2));
    ui_.label_pitchValue->setText(QString::number(msg.orientation.y, 'f', 2));
    ui_.label_yawValue->setText(QString::number(msg.orientation.z, 'f', 2));
    updateTimeImuEuler = ros::Time::now().toSec();
  }
}
```

And they are all working fine, I dont need to click on them to see the changed text.

Comment: I just tried the code that shows and works correctly, you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: It worked for me too. Could you provide more details how you update the item.

Comment: Perhaps tell the window to repaint after you modify the widgets, though it should work automatically...

Comment: You might try to call `ui_.list->update()` on your `QListWidget` after you change its items.

Comment: @vahancho I added `ui_.list_movil->update()` but is not working for me. Should I add more stuff?

Comment: @hecperleo : I tried out a small example by setting the text on a QListWidget and it worked just fine. You need to narrow down the problem, try to reproduce it on a sample Qt application. If you then post your problem with a MCVE, then people might be able to help you out.